# Synchronous jQuery calls, without putting everything in the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, deprecated, synchronous

Is it possible to get a JSON in jQuery synchronously without using the `async: false` option (which apparently has been deprecated)? I also would prefer not to put everything into the success function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no other option than `async: false`. I wouldn't recommend it if there were.

For the success function, you can simply pass another function that will be executed.

For example:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: myUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    success: myFunc
} );

function myFunc( datas ) {
    // do what you should do in a success function
}
```

Comment: What about when/then (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)? It doesn't guarantee the response from ajax call?

Comment: This means that I have to put all of the code for the page in that function? This is a dictionary lookup, which I'll be needing across all parts of the code.

Comment: @matino, doesn't that accomplish the exact same thing as just setting up a success function? I don't need to wait for multiple AJAX calls to finish, I just need one to finish synchronously.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why I asked :)

Comment: @AndrewC You can use a singleton to store/retrieve this dictionary and use it across your codebase.

Answer (score 3):

Since ajax methods on jQuery return a `Deferred Object` (jQuery 1.5+) you could also write

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function() {
  // do what you should do in a success function
});
```

Comment: Can you please point out what's the difference when using `done` over "simple success" callback?

Comment: the simple success callback is defined *inside* the ajax object/function itself while the use of `Promises/A` pattern gives you more flexibility and code scalability (e.g you can attach programmatically a done() or a fail() function or even attach multiple done() function). Beside this also promotes code consistency (you could use this pattern potentially on every asynchronous task)

Answer (score 1):

Not reasonably. Trying to force the request to be Synchronous without using asyc:false is possible, but a waste of effort in my opinion. In pretty much every scenario you want to use async:true, you will be able to accomplish all of the same things with async:true as you can with async:false. It's just a matter of how you structure your code.

If you look at the current version of the source file that executes the AJAX request:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js

You will see it still uses the async field on the settings object, this field is passed directly into the Open method of the XMLHttpRequest object.  So using the default implementation all you can do, is set "async: false".

```
if ( s.username ) {
    xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password );
} else {
    xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async ); 
}
```

Now assuming you are really stubborn and want to do this without setting "async:false", you could get really bold and write a custom ajaxTransport and register it with a custom data type.

Here is an example I wrote that creates a custom transport object with a send and abort method, and registers it with the dataType 'mine'.  So when you specify dataType 'mine' in your ajaxSettings object it will use this custom transport instead of the one built into jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/xrzc7/  Notice there are two ajax requests one with the 'mine' dataType that show the alert, and one without the data type that does not show the alert. My ajaxTransport in this example isn't fully functional, its just to illustrate that you can swap in your own send function.

I wouldn't advise writing your own ajaxTransport for jQuery because it really isn't neccessary in my opinion, but to answer your question I'm suggesting it as an option.

You should pay close attention to how the default ajaxTransport in jquery is written, and how it interacts with the settings object and callback methods when writing your custom ajaxTransport.  Your send function would obviously force a "false" value as the async parameter of the XMLHttpRequest.open method.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js - this is the current source code for the default ajaxTransport mechanism.

Hope this helps, or perhaps persuades you to always use async:true. :-D